# When is a file not a file system object?

Tags: file, winapi, windows-shell, filesystemobject

I have code which enumerates the Favorites folder (recursively) by means of the shell API. I use the `GetAttributesOf` function to obtain the attributes of each object I find.

Because I never advance upward, my expectation is that all items I encounter will be file system objects. This probably isn't true of all sub-directories, but I am pretty confident it is true of the one in question.

Despite my confidence, I verify that the attributes include `SFGAO_FILESYSTEM`. If they do not, then I log a message and skip the item, because there is no hope of being able to do my job. I expected that I would never see the logging or have to skip an item, but I put in the verification anyway because that's how I roll.

Weeks later, my excellent QA engineer tells me he is seeing my program misbehave with respect to a particular item, and about the time that it does, he sees in the log that the item did not have the file system bit set and had to be skipped. The item in question is, we have good reason to believe, a file.

Since I originally wrote this question, we've seen cases in which several items in the enumeration claim not to be file system items. The trouble seems to last a very short time but long enough to screw up the flags for as many as a half-dozen items.

When is a file not a file system object?

Comment: are you enumerating folders that may have children may have some other views, like Temporary Internet Files or GAC?

Comment: I'm not enumerating either of those folders.

I'll edit the question to be more specific.

Comment: Is the call to `GetAttributeOf()` itself failing, leaving your flags variable unchanged from what you initialize it to?

Comment: Good question, but in that case I would have thrown an exception before getting a chance to test for `SFGAO_FILESYSTEM`.

Comment: Are you using GetAttributesOf to query multiple items, or just one (and if the latter, why not use IShellItem::GetAttributes?).  GetAttributesOf returns the attributes that the supplied shell items have in common, so a single non-file object will suppress the SFGAO_FILESYSTEM flag.  Finally, are you logging any further information, like the name of the non-file object?

Comment: Just one item. We also log the file system path with which we created the object, but the code presently bails out before we try to extract any further clues from the object. Experimentally attempting to use the object as if the flag had been set tends to yield Win32 error 5 for some operation or another. (I don't have the code in front of me right now.)

Comment: Check whether the file is shortcut and also verify by chance, do you use reserved name mentioned here?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: The file is not a shortcut. We created it. The filename does not include reserved characters or names. We filtered that before creating  the file, plus we can observe the filename in the log and it's boring. :-)

Comment: Are files being created in the folder (or subfolders) while you're enumerating the folder?  And what's the extension of the file that's failing?

Comment: What value does `GetAttributesOf` return? Which bits are set? What is the object's name (e.g. `GetDisplayNameOf`)?

Answer (score 1):

It's unclear whether you're on a legacy filesystem or NTFS, but there are a couple of things that could potentially kill a filesystem bit - Vista introduced symlinks, which are not the same thing as regular shortcuts and since they parse "client-side" they might not count as filesystem objects per se. Likewise with directory reparse points. The SFGAO enumeration isn't completely a 1:1 representation of what's going on in NTFS, so take its information with a grain of salt.

There's also an outside chance that bad blocks might be causing Windows to report the filesystem bit inconsistently. That becomes your only explanation if the same files are sometimes reported as filesystem objects and sometimes not.

Comment: It's NTFS, but there are no symlinks or directory reparse points.

Comment: However, you raise another interesting possibility. This code is running inside a VM. If the virtualized disk reports bogus transient bad block errors, that could help explain the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Are you doing this recursively?

If you descend into an archive (e.g. a zip or cab file) you will see non-filesystem objects.

Similarly, if you descend into a directory with a desktop.ini file you may see non-filesystem objects (but it depends on what the COM object referenced by desktop.ini does).

Though in both of these cases you'd expect to see a not-found error rather than access-denied if you tried to access the object as a file.  Is there any chance you don't have file system permissions on the offending objects?

NTFS features such as symlinks and reparse points are reported as filesystem objects, so they are definitely not the problem.

Comment: We're doing this recursively, but there are no zip files involved. Some folders involved do contain "desktop.ini" files, but their contents are pretty boring, on the order of overriding the display name. It is of course possible that we lack permission to access the files, but a file system object to which one lacks permission is still a file system object.